# How to use loader to import local typescript package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, loader, npm-package

I am developing my own typescript package which can be imported in react projects.

In order to test it while developing, I have linked the package locally using `npm link` and created a typescript react project using `create-react-app` cli.

When importing my package, following error happens.

```
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

How can I fix it?